# Does a .net bool[] use one bit or one byte per item?

Tags: .net, arrays, storage

In .net, does a bool[] use one bit or one byte per array item? ie, does it automatically pack the bool values? I know a single bool uses 1 byte, but maybe the CLR has a special case for bool[]...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concerning size, it stores an array of bools as an array of bytes, no special case there.

You might want to check the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class if you want to pack data.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx). `bool[]` gets no special treatment by the CLR.

Answer (score 4):

One byte per value. I'm trying to find where this is actually specified (if indeed it is) but it's true for the current .NET CLR.

EDIT: This is *sort of* confirmed by printing `sizeof(bool)` which prints 1 - although the `sizeof` operator in C# doesn't end up calling the `sizeof` IL instruction...

Comment: What's the size of a bool in other languages (Java/C/C++)?

Comment: In Java a boolean is 1 byte as well (in an array).

Comment: In C/C++ it's also 1 byte size

Comment: The size of bool in C++ isn't specified. It is only guaranteed that it should be at least the size of char (at least 8 bits), and at most equal to the size of long. I think really old versions of VC++ and g++ implemented it as an enum typedef, which would make it as big as int. In newer versions of VC++, it is a built-in type of size 1 byte; it's probably the same for newer versions of g++ as well.